# how to create json array using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to create a json response for a report. Something like this:

```
var data = [
  ["", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda"],
  ["2008", 10, 11, 12, 13],
  ["2009", 20, 11, 14, 13],
  ["2010", 30, 15, 12, 13]
];
```

Im using jackson library and i create a JsonGenerator, this is the code i have:

```
String[] cols = new String[5]; //Number of report columns

JsonFactory jfactory = new JsonFactory();
JsonGenerator jGenerator = jfactory.createJsonGenerator(response.getOutputStream(),JsonEncoding.UTF8);
jGenerator.writeStartArray();

jGenerator.writeStartArray();
jGenerator.writeStringField(cols[0], "");
//until...
jGenerator.writeStringField(cols[4], "Honda");
jGenerator.writeEndArray();
jGenerator.writeStartArray();
jGenerator.writeStringField(cols[0], "2008");
//until...
jGenerator.writeStringField(cols[4], "13");
jGenerator.writeEndArray();
//and the same with the next rows...

jGenerator.writeEndArray();
```

The problem is when setting the first value i get this error:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException: Can not write a field name, expecting a value
```

Comment: what do you expect your json to look like?

Comment: just as the first code (var=data) an array of arrays

Comment: I need to return something like this: [["1","2"],["3","4"],["5","6"]];

Comment: is there any way i can create that and return it as a response? im using handsontable http://handsontable.com/demo/understanding_reference.html

Comment: in json, items have two aspects, a name and a value. This is what the arguments to writeStringField are. The first argument is the name, you're passing in cols[x] - but cols has never been initialised (in the code you posted), so you're passing in a null value which I'd imagine is what causes the exception.

Comment: Do not use `writeXXXField()` to write array elements because array elements are not fields but simple values, use methods that output simple values like `writeNumber()` or `writeString()`.

Comment: ok i see that problem, now i already gave names to my columns String[] cols = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4"}; but the exception still present.

Answer (score 7):

Can you build the array as an object before writing it, rather than bothering with all the individual pieces?

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ArrayNode array = mapper.createArrayNode();

int i = 0;
while (i < 6) {
    array.add(mapper.createArrayNode().add("" + i++).add("" + i++));
}
System.out.println(array);
```

Results in:

```
[["0","1"],["2","3"],["4","5"]]
```

If you're not dealing with several megabytes of data or very tight memory constraints, this might turn out to be more maintainable as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
    JsonGenerator jg = new JsonFactory().createJsonGenerator(System.out);
    jg.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS, true);
    jg.writeStartArray();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 6)
    {
        jg.writeStartArray();
        jg.writeObject(i++);
        jg.writeObject(i++);
        jg.writeEndArray();
    }

    jg.writeEndArray();
    jg.flush();
```

OUTPUT:

```
 [["0","1"],["2","3"],["4","5"]]
```

Do you need a json like this...?